# The session ID is not given only in the local environment when a user tries to log in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

Even though I did not change any code, the login function does not work, which had been working. Even though I put the correct email address and password, it will be redirected to the login page.
I do not use devise.

First, I thought some coding is wrong, but according to the log, it says the email address and password are correct and it tries to redirect to the top page properly.

Next, I used the tool `Burp Suite` which tracks the data such as session ID in between the browser and server (local proxy).
And I found out that the session ID is not given after the login, and it brings the error caused by `authenticate_user` so that login has been failed.
I want to find out the reason and solve it.

In addition, I used the tool `ngrok` which enables users to visit my localhost.
Then surprisingly, the user outside of my local environment was able to log in successfully.
And `Burp Suite` showed that the session ID was given property in this case.

Therefore, only when I try to log in from my local environment, the session ID isn’t given.
Recently, I did not edit any code but did these tasks below.

- Install Git.
- Pushed my “app1” to GitHub through Git.
- Install SourseTree, and connected with my GitHub.
- Clone my “app1” from GitHub through SourceTree, and named it “app2”.

Before doing these tasks, I added this code below. But it does not change the situation even though I comment out it.

**application.rb**

```
config.session_store :cookie_store, expire_after: 8.hours
```

All the problems occurred after these tasks.

#### Code

**routes.rb**

```
get "login" => "users#login_form"
post "login" => "users#login"
post "logout" => "users#logout"
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
  before_action :set_current_user
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  caches_action :set_current_user, :authenticate_user, :forbid_login_user

  def set_current_user
    @current_user = User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end

  def authenticate_user
    if @current_user == nil
      flash[:notice] = "You need to log in"
      redirect_to("/login")
    end
  end

  def forbid_login_user
    if @current_user
      flash[:notice] = "You are already logged in"
      redirect_to("/")
    end
  end
end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
before_action :authenticate_user, {except: [:new, :create, :login_form, :login]}
before_action :forbid_login_user, {only: [:new, :create, :login_form, :login]}
before_action :ensure_correct_user, {only: [:edit, :update]}
before_action :ensure_correct_user_account, {only: [:setting_password, :update_password, :setting_email, :update_email, :delete_account, :destroy]}
caches_action :index, :show, :follow, :new, :create, :edit, :user_params, :update, :destroy, :login_form, :login, :logout, :likes, :ensure_correct_user, :followings, :followers, :top

def login
  @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
  if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:password])
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    flash[:notice] = "You have successfully logged in"
    redirect_to("/")
  else
    @error_message = "Email address or password is incorrect"
    @email = params[:email]
    @password = params[:password]
    render("users/login_form")
  end
end

def login_form
end

def logout
  session[:user_id] = nil
  flash[:notice] = "You have successfully logged out"
  redirect_to("/login")
end
```

When a user successfully login, it redirects to “/“ (the top page).

#### Log

It’s a log when I tried to log in. Seeing `Started GET "/"`, the user seems to log in successfully. But then the log says `Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user rendered or redirected`, and it redirects to `"/login"`.

```
Started POST "/login" for ::1 at 2021-08-24 14:44:31 +0900
Processing by UsersController#login as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"JBcKtTsdCT0JXgyIfzjKVqi/8KEz4pRmUXB2Kybn8eHcnz7UKXoMsbBRkBCnoUqwnIdi4hUkZ/6oQKFVqMyG/g==", "email"=>"hoge", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}
  User Load (35.1ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IS NULL LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:9
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'hoge' LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:255
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 422ms (ActiveRecord: 41.9ms)


Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2021-08-24 14:44:32 +0900
Processing by UsersController#top as HTML
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IS NULL LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:9
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/login
Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)


Started GET "/login" for ::1 at 2021-08-24 14:44:32 +0900
Processing by UsersController#login_form as HTML
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IS NULL LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:9
  Rendering users/login_form.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/login_form.html.erb within layouts/application (0.9ms)
  CACHE User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IS NULL LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:51
Completed 200 OK in 244ms (Views: 233.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

#### Display of Burp Suite

How the session ID is given when the user login from outside when I used `ngrok`. You can see both the “Cookie” and “Set-Cookie” are displayed.
[image]

When I try login from the local environment. Both the “Cookie” and “Set-Cookie” cannot be seen.
[image]

#### What I have tried

Reboot for the server and my computer did not solve the problem.
Several browsers (Google Chrome, Firefox, and Brave) showed the same result.

#### Versions

ruby 2.6.4p104
RubyGems 3.0.3
Rails 5.2.3
Burp Suite Community Edition 2021.8.2

#### Postscript

These works did not change the situation.

- Put `bundle exec rake tmp:cache:clear` on a command.
- Put `rails tmp:clear` on a command.
- Delete the session history in `users_controller.rb`

```
def login_form
  reset_session
  session[:user_id] = nil
  session.delete(:user_id)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by myself.
I made the file `session_store.rb` in the past, and it was the cause.

config > initializers > session_store.rb

```
app_name = "app_name"
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: "_app_name_session", expire_after: 8.hours, secure: true
```

`secure: true` disables http to pass the cookie, so I could not log in only on the localhost. I forgot to delete this file.

I deleted `session_store.rb`, and wrote the code below in `application.rb`.

```
config.session_store :cookie_store, expire_after: 8.hours, secure: Rails.env.production?
```

Now, the log in function does work on the localhost too.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach to authentication altogether is:

```
# app/errors/authentication_error.rb
class AuthenticationError < StandardError; end
```

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  rescue_from 'AuthenticationError', with: :deny_access

  private 

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end

  def user_signed_in?
    current_user.present?
  end

  def authenticate_user!
    raise AuthenticationError unless user_signed_in?
  end

  def deny_access
    flash[:notice] = "You need to log in"
    redirect_to login_path
  end
end
```

Instead of setting the current user with a callback use a method which memoizes its value. This removes the potential for issues tied to the order of callbacks. This should be the only method that knows how the user is persisted in the session.

Use a secure by default approach instead of explicitly authenticating. This means that instead of calling `before_action :authenticate_user, {except: [:new, :create, :login_form, :login]}` you call `skip_before_action :authenticate_user, only: [:new, :create, :login_form, :login]` to opt out of authorization.

Raising an error if the user is not authenticated will save you a bunch of debugging time when testing as you can disable `rescue_from` to ensure that errors are raised.

And instead of jamming everything into a monster UsersController create a controller which has the single responsibility of signing the user in and out:

```
scope controller: 'sessions' do
  get :login, action: :new, as: :login
  post :login, action: :create
  delete :logout, action: :destroy, as: :logout
  get :logout, action: :destroy, as: :logout
end
```

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :deny_access_to_signed_in_users, if: :user_signed_in?,        

  # GET /login
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # POST /login
  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      flash[:notice] = "You have successfully logged in"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Email address or password is incorrect"
      @user = User.new(**params.permit(:email, :password))
      render :new
    end
  end

  # DELETE /logout
  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    flash[:notice] = "You have successfully logged out"
    redirect_to login_path
  end

  private

  def deny_access_to_signed_in_users
    flash[:notice] = "You are already logged in!"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

```
# app/views/sessions/new.html.erb

<h1>Sign in</h1>
<%= form_with(model: @user, path: login_path, method: :post, local: true) do |form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :email %>
    <%= form.email_field :email %>
  </div> 
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :password %>
    <%= form.email_field :email %>
  </div> 
  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit 'Sign in' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, and very sorry for the late reply. I was able to solve the problem by myself, and the cause was on a different file from what you mentioned.
I would like to refer to your code as well to make a better log in function.